# Python browse inside of a given path and take all files with extension ".txt", but paths are stored inside of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, dictionary

I have dictionary with modules and their paths
modulesDict that looks like this:

```
'Module1': ['folder1/folder2/Module1'], 'Module2': ['folder1/folder2/Module2'] , etc
```

Now I need to make a script in python that will browse each of the paths and collect all files with the .txt extension inside and store them in a unique place for that one specific module.

My current code is:

```
for j in modulesDict[path]:
if j != 0:
    continue
    for file in os.listdir(j):
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
             pathList.append(file)
```

when I run it I get an error: KeyError: X for the last item in the dict.

Short example:
So I have a dict that looks like 'Module1': ['folder1/folder2/Module1'], 'Module2': ['folder1/folder2/Module2'] etc..
and I need to make a script that will browse each of the paths, take all files with the .txt extension from there, and store them in a unique list. Example: path ['folder1/folder2/Module1'] contains inside module1.txt, module1.1.txt, module1.2.txt, and I need to store them in a list called list_module1 = [module1.txt, module1.1.txt, module1.2.txt]

please advice.

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: Not sure what else to add, so I have a dict that looks like 'Module1': ['folder1/folder2/Module1'], 'Module2': ['folder1/folder2/Module2'] etc.. and I need to make a script that will browse each of the paths and take all files with .txt extension from there, and store them in some unique list. Example: path ['folder1/folder2/Module1'] contains inside module1.txt, module1.1.txt, module1.2.txt, and I need to store them in a list called list_module1 = [module1.txt, module1.1.txt, module1.2.txt]. I will post this also in question. Thanks.

Comment: A [mre] means something we can copy and paste and run on our end. Describing what you have requires us to make assumptions of your data and forces us to try to recreate said data.

Comment: You can use the `glob` module to list out all files in a directory. You can then update your dictionary accordingly. Also, you might need to consider `for key, value in modulesDict.items()` to iterate your dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two nested list comprehensions to produce a list of list of files:

```
from os import listdir
result = [[f for file in pathList\
        for f in listdir(file) if f.endswith(".txt")]\
    for pathList in modulesDict.values()]
```

Similarly, you can use a list comprehension nested inside a `dictionary comprehension` to produce a dictionary with **module names** as `keys` and **list of files** as `values`:

```
from os import listdir
result = {name: [f for file in pathList\
        for f in listdir(file) if f.endswith(".txt")]\
    for name, pathList in modulesDict.items()}
```

... or **file paths** as values:

```
from os import listdir
# As list:
result_list = [[os.path.join(file, f) for file in pathList\
        for f in listdir(file) if f.endswith(".txt")]\
    for pathList in modulesDict.values()]
# As dictionary:
result_dict = {name: [os.path.join(file, f) for file in pathList\
        for f in listdir(file) if f.endswith(".txt")]\
    for name, pathList in modulesDict.items()}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I missed one small thing, how to add my default path in search criteria, so default_path + path from dict?

Comment: You can use `os.path.join()` to join *folder paths* and *filenames* in a proper way.

Comment: I have default_path = 'C:/d/projects/project_name/software/', and that should be prefix for all other paths, so C:/d/projects/project_name/software/folder1/folder2/Module1 is the full path to the module. So how would the call look, cause this won't work: [os.path.join(default_path, file, f)

Comment: I am not sure why it wouldn't work. As you can check here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join , the second argument `*paths` has a `*` meaning the method will unpack any number of nested folders you pass in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```py
from pathlib import Path # a python standard library
modulesDict = {'Module1': ['folder1/folder2/Module1'], 'Module2': ['folder1/folder2/Module2']}
output = {}
for module, folder_paths in modulesDict.items():
    for folder_path in folder_paths:
        output[module] = list(map(str, list(Path(folder_path).glob("*.txt"))))
```

The above code outputs something like this:

```
{
  'Module1': ['path/to/text/file1', 'path/to/text/file/2', etc..],
  'Module2': ['path/to/text/file1', 'path/to/text/file/2', etc..],
  .
  .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob

# Input Dictionary
input_ = {
    "path1": "path/to/folder1",
    "path2": "path/to/folder2"
}

output_ = {}

for path_ in input_.keys():
    # uncomment the below line to see which keys you have in the input_ dictionary
    # print(path_)
    output_[path] = glob.glob(input_[path] + "/*.txt"),
```

Output -

```
{
    "path1": ["path/to/folder1/1.txt", "path/to/folder1/1.txt"]
    "path2": []   # Empty list if there are no txt files in the module.
}
```

Brief explanation -

- [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) library can be used to find files in paths.
- We can store the new paths in another dictionary with the same keys to avoid confusion. This way we can get unique lists for each path in the input_ dictionary inside a single object.
- If there are not `txt` files in a module, then `glob.glob` returns an empty list.

Regarding your error, it seems like you are trying to access a key which is not in the dictionary. You can try to debug by adding a `print(path_)` in the for loop

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When run this, I keep getting "Exception has occurred: KeyError
X" and the path of the last item from the list

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate a bit more, or maybe if possible paste the error to the question with the stacktrace (with dummy data if the data is sensitive). In my experience, this error occurs when we try to access a key in a dictionary that does not exist. [Reference](https://realpython.com/python-keyerror/#:~:text=A%20Python%20KeyError%20exception%20is,set%20of%20values%20to%20another.)